# Почему работает обращение к приватным полям класса?

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, visual-c++

У меня есть метод `middle()`, который является публичным методом класса `Point2D`:

```
Point2D middle(const Point2D& point)
{
    Point2D result;

    result.x = (this->x + point.x) / 2;
    result.y = (this->y + point.y) / 2;

    return result;
}
```

При этом поля `x` и `y` являются приватными. Почему обращение к приватным полям объектов `point` и `result` не вызывают ошибки?

Comment: Потому что это метод класса `Point2D`.

Comment: Читать учебники нужно внимательней...

Comment: В первую очередь вы сами должны объяснить, почему вас это удивляет.

Answer (score 5):

Потому что вы обращаетесь к ним из метода **того же класса**.

Так сказать, "грануляция" доступа в С++ идет на уровне классов, а не отдельных переменных. Так что как бы ни были объявлены поля в классе, **метод того же класса** всегда может к ним обратиться (в самом деле, если было бы иначе - то какой вообще смысл в таких полях?!).

Другое дело - методы других классов или даже производных классов. Для них нужно объявлять поля соответственно как `public` (доступны всем) или `protected` (доступны потомкам).